# Просим извинения за предоставленные неудобства (?!)

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, управление

Только что прочитал фразу: "**Просим извинения** за предоставленные неудобства". Обычно просят прощения,  а извинения приносят, вот и заинтересовало: будет ли ошибкой извинения? Также интересно, а почему устоялись сочетания именно в том виде, что я описал выше?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<<Обычно просят прощения, а извинения приносят>>

Полагаю, что извинение (-я) всё же следует, как и прощение, запрашивать, если дело связано с конкретным лицом. Оборот «приносим свои извинения» допустим в качестве превентивного признания собственных ошибок со стороны общественно-административных структур в обращениях к потерпевшим и подверженным неудобствам группам граждан (на вокзалах за задержку рейсов; от коммунальщиков за отключение воды и т. п.)

*Предоставленные* неудобства — это неудобства, сделанные намеренно. И просить за них прощения — это издевательство. Правильно: доставленные неудобства.

Answer (score 2):

Мне не слишком нравится сочетание "просить извинения". Лучше, имхо, всё-таки "просим извинить", если уж "просим прощения" почему-то не подходит. Тут дело не только в том, что, как Вы верно заметили, извинения приносят, но и в том, что "извинения" восприниматься и как то, чего просят - и как то, что по этой просьбе дают. Это путает.

Впрочем, тем самым я частично ответил и на вопрос о том, почему устоялись именно такие сочетания. Полный ответ, боюсь, Вам не даст никто, как и на почти всякий вопрос с "почему". так уж сложилось, причинно-следственную связь далеко не  всегда удаётся проследить, даже в том довольно редком случае, когда она, эта связь, есть.

Касательно же "предоставленных неудобств" - согласен. Несочетаемая пара. Но и "доставленные неудобства" - ничуть не лучше. Стилистически правильным тут было бы "причиненные неудобства".

Comment: Спрошу в этой теме. Иногда слышу такое выражение: "**Я извиняюсь**".

Так вообще правильно говорить? **Как это воспринимается?** Как разговорное? Как просторечие? Или как обычное нормальное выражение?

Comment: @Nikolja, этот вопрос, лучше обсуждать [здесь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2798/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Nikolja, тут действительно мало места на все разговоры об этом "Я извиняюсь". Вопрос неоднозначен, а там, куда Вас послали, я действительно сказал все или почти все, что мог.  
Предпочитаю "Извините", но "Извиняюсь" за ошибку не считаю.

Answer (score 1):

ПРЕДОСТАВИТЬ [дать возможность обладать, распоряжаться, пользоваться чем-л.; делать что-л.; действовать каким-л. образом] что кому-чему. Предоставить комнату приезжим; Предоставить слово оратору; На станции Миллерово Григорию... предоставили обывательскую подводу (Ш.); Распоряжение дуэлью, с общего согласия, было предоставлено мне (Купр.); Предоставить правлению кооператива право распоряжаться землёй. ([Управление в русском языке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C))

Неудобства — вовсе не то, что клиент желает **получить в свое распоряжение**. Их также невозможно **предоставить** (то есть передать в распоряжение клиента) ненамеренно.

(1) Неудобства доставляют или причиняют, а не предоставляют.

(2) В официальных письмах принято **приносить** извинения, хотя выражение "просить извинения" присутствует в словарях  (например, [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?insa=x&ab=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Корректно:

**Приносим извинения за доставленные (причиненные) неудобства.**

ДОСТАВИТЬ, -ставлю, -ставишь; св. 1. кого-что. Привезти, принести и т.п. к месту назначения. Д. пассажиров. Д. груз. Д. посылку в срок. Д. телеграмму на дом. // Привезти или привести кого-л. куда-л. в сопровождении охраны, конвоя; препроводить. Солдаты доставили пленного в часть. 2. что. Дать, предоставить, обеспечить. Д. возможность путешествия. Д. случай познакомиться. Д. покой и независимость. Доставил случай убедиться в его правоте. **3. что. Причинить, вызвать. Д. много хлопот.** Спектакль доставил истинное удовольствие. Поход доставил немало трудностей. <Доставлять, -яю, -яешь; нсв. Доставляться, -яется; страд. Доставление, -я; ср. Д. корреспонденции. Д. удобств. Д. неприятностей. Доставка, -и; ж. (1 зн.). Д. газет и писем. Заплатить за доставку. Телеграмма с доставкой на дом. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C))